# Two files including each other causes errors that cannot be fixed by forward declaring

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

So, read clearly...

```
// scene.h
#include "Entity.h"

class Scene
{
public:
   Entity createEntity() {
        return Entity(this);
   }
};
```

So, that was the `Scene` class, then we've got the `Entity` class

```
// entity.h
class Entity
{
    public:
        Entity(Scene* scene) {
            m_handle = scene->m_registry.create() // entt library
        }
};
```

I tried forward declaring these classes, but since they access eachothers' functions and class variables and etc, it's kinda impossible.

I was trying to create a Scene that holds Entities. Since c++ has this strange issue when two files are including each other, I don't really know what to do since my classes has to access each others' functions and variables and etc, forward declaring didn't really work...

Comment: Move the implementation of `Entity` constructor into a source file. Then in `entity.h` it would be sufficient to forward-declare `Scene`

Comment: *"but since they access eachothers' functions and class variables and etc, it's kinda impossible."* -- it is easy to hide solutions by over-using pronouns, in this case "they". What exactly are "they"? Does "they" mean the class implementations? Or does "they" mean just what needs to be in the headers (class definitions, which includes just declarations for member functions, constructors, etc.)?

Comment: Moving the implementation to cpp files will solve your issue. But my 2 cents: if you're having this problem it *usually* indicates a bad design - circular dependencies etc.

Answer (score -2):

1. Use pragma in each header file:

```
#pragma once
```

2. Or include guards:

Scene.h

```
#ifndef PROJECT_SCENE_H
#define PROJECT_SCENE_H
// your scene class
#endif // PROJECT_SCENE_H
```

Entity.h

```
#ifndef PROJECT_ENTITY_H
#define PROJECT_ENTITY_H
// your entity class
#endif // PROJECT_ENTITY_H
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.